Strange random packet delay on client [Java Spring/Netty + WebSocket]
There is a server (Java Spring + Netty), there is a client in Javascript. The server and client communicate via sockets. The server sends packets (about 200 bytes each) to the client at a fixed frequency of 100 millisseconds. My home laptop and my phone are connected to the same Wi-Fi network. I run the client on my laptop and phone at the same time. On the displays I can see the delay between received packets on the clients. If on a laptop this delay is between 80 and 120 milliseconds, then on the phone something strange is happening. The delay can increase to 1 second and more, and subsequent packets in the queue are naturally delivered almost instantly after the delay. There is no such problem on the phone if you turn on mobile Internet or another Wi-Fi network. There are about a dozen other users from all over the world who are experiencing the same problems on their mobile devices. What is this? And how can you fix this?
I tried changing the server settings, but it had no effect.
